# Vue3 emit value to parent

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to Vue and am currently creating a table with dynamically displayed abbreviations.

I try to emit a searchTerm from my child component to the parent, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

My problem is, that when I try to seperate the search input and the table, the value is not emitted to the parent.

I tried solving this by defining props and a export default, but somehow my component doesn't accept this.

```js
const SzNavbar = {
  template: `
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span>Test - Shorty</span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>`
}

const SzSearchfield = {
  template: `
        <form class="mt-5">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="mr-2" for="txtSearch">Suche:</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchbegriff"/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button type="button" @click="onSearch" class="btn btn-primary margin">Suche</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Search Term: {{ searchTerm }}</p>
            </div>
          </form>`,
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch() {
      this.$emit('search', this.searchTerm)
      console.log(this.searchTerm)
    }
  }
}

const SzShorty = {
  template: `<sz-searchfield></sz-searchfield>`,
  components: {
    'sz-searchfield': SzSearchfield
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
    };
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    'sz-shorty': SzShorty,
    'sz-searchfield': SzSearchfield,
    'sz-navbar': SzNavbar,
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sz-navbar></sz-navbar>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <sz-shorty></sz-shorty>
      <!-- <test-bar></test-bar> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have polished your code to include only the relevant sections which makes it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help anybody who is trying to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to the `search` event that is emitted from your child at the parent component. Notice the `@search` listener at `SzShorty` where you include `sz-searchfield` component

Read more about [Vue emit](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html) in the documentation.

I have added a `console.log()` at the parent component which prints `search` along with the search term emitted from the child component.

```js
const SzSearchfield = {
  template: `
        <form class="mt-5">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="mr-2" for="txtSearch">Suche:</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchbegriff"/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button type="button" @click="onSearch" class="btn btn-primary margin">Suche</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Search Term: {{ searchTerm }}</p>
            </div>
          </form>`,
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch() {
      this.$emit('search', this.searchTerm)
      console.log(this.searchTerm)
    }
  }
}

const SzShorty = {
  template: `<sz-searchfield @search="onSearch"></sz-searchfield>`,
  components: {
    'sz-searchfield': SzSearchfield
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch: (val) => {
      console.log("onSearch", val)
    }
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    'sz-shorty': SzShorty,
    'sz-searchfield': SzSearchfield
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <sz-shorty></sz-shorty>
      <!-- <test-bar></test-bar> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from a child to a parent component by means of Vue's built-in $emit() method. The first parameter of $emit is the event that should be listened for in the parent component. The second (optional) parameter is the data value to pass.

Please modify the code to listen to the search event that is emitted from the child component to parent component.